# List<String> not fully mapped to String in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Input:

```
var message= constants.institutions['colleges'].map((e) => '$e : $count');
print(message);
```

Output:

```
(School of Excellence : 110, Boarding School : 254, High School : 1660, ..., Higher Secondary School : 512, KG : 750)
```

I'm trying to log list of schools and student strength (for example). It's 25 schools.
Unfortunately it's printing `...` instead of other schools

Comment: Yes, the name school and student strength is combined from different different lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` here is an `Iterable<String>` because `.map()` returns an `Iterable`. If you want to see the full output you can do something like:

```dart
final message = constants.institutions['colleges'].map((e) => '$e : $count').toList();
// convert to a list
print(message);  // will now print all elements
```

or

```dart
print(message.join('\n'));  // join strings with a newline between each
```

Comment: Wow!, It's working and exciting. Can you explain the root cause of getting the false result?

Comment: If you take a look at the docs for `Iterable.toString()` https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Iterable/toString.html : > The default representation always contains the first three elements. If there are less than a hundred elements in the iterable, it also contains the last two elements.
It doesn't try to print all of them, but will choose a number to print based on the size

Answer (score 0):

Your data is mapping correctly. You are getting `...` in output because your data is very large. If you try to map and print a large amount of data in Flutter, it just prints the first and last part of the data.

Comment: But, I need to convert it string fully

Comment: You can do something like that:
`constants.institutions['colleges'].map((e) => print('$e : $count'));`